# What's the simplest way in ruby to feed a script items, press submit and have it email me those items in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I'm building a small app where a user will input a date from 3 selectors, month, day and year. They click "submit" and I want it to email me with that date. What's the best way or best library to do that? I figure it can be as simple as a ruby script on my server, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a normal script that runs on your server in response to the users post.  From within that script you send an email.

http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/et_mail_rails.htm. 
http://ruby.about.com/od/tasks/ss/smtp.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you can deploy whatever you want, something like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) is lighter than a full Ruby app. OTOH, doing this in Rails would take minutes.

I'd avoid writing a "simple" Ruby script, otherwise you'll likely re-invent several wheels, although you don't specifically state this is a web app. If it's an *actual* app, you might want to clarify that.

Comment: It's an HTML 5 app using the iUI framework to look like an iPhone app. The goal is to have the user input the date and have that date emailed to me. That's pretty much the end function of this script as it relates to the app

Comment: @ZackShapiro I'd probably still just use RoR as a service at least, if that Rails plugin is well and truly dead (which it looks like it is). YMMV.

Comment: I guess the question I'm asking is, how do I call a ruby script in HTML 5, feed the ruby script some POST items and then have it email me those items?

Comment: A script would need to open a port, listen for connections, process the data, etc. Don't know if HTML5 can do that. The other option is to just process a normal form submission via HTTP and mail out the other end. You could start up your own webrick etc. (it's super-easy) and handle things like form submission errors yourself, I suppose.

Comment: I'd very much like to do the process a normal submission form and mail out a request. How would I do this?

Comment: @ZackShapiro I'd just use Rails and its built-in ActiveMailer.